# How to detect view port area of div by JQuery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have div whose height is huge because it has huge content inside. when i scroll down then suppose 30% of that div is visible in my browser. this could be 30% or 40% anything. now i want to detect the height and width of visible area of that div.

i got this code but not sure does it fulfill my requirement?

```
  var height = $("#example").height();

  // Get the topScroll position
  var scrollTop = $("#example").scrollTop();

  // Get the difference (content shown)
  var shown = height - scrollTop;

  // Display the shown amount
  $("#shown").html(shown);
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/zejice/1/edit?html,output)

help me with suggestion or any better way. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect the **visible (in-viewport) height** you can create a simple plugin like:

```
function inViewport($el) {
    var H = $(window).height(),
        r = $el[0].getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
    return Math.max(0, t>0? H-t : (b<H?b:H));  
}
```

you can than use it like:

```
$(window).on("scroll resize", function(){
  console.log( inViewport($('#elementID')) ); // n px in viewport
});
```

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yg991dsq/)***

you can easily extend the above plugin to return the visible width like:

```
function inViewport($el) {
    var H = $(window).height(),
        W = $(window).width(),
        bcr = $el[0].getBoundingClientRect(), t=bcr.top,  b=bcr.bottom,
                                              l=bcr.left, r=bcr.right; 
    return {
        visibleHeight : Math.max(0, t>0? H-t : (b<H?b:H)),
        visibleWidth  : Math.max(0, l>0? W-l : (l<W?l:W))
   };
}
```

which you can than use (since it returns an Object) like:

```
var $el = $("#elementID");

$(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
  var amountOf = inViewport( $el );
  console.log(
      amountOf.visibleHeight,
      amountOf.visibleWidth
  );
});
```

Comment: why u did not use div height - div scrollTop; ? if it is not right then explain what was the problem in that approach?

Comment: why did not u consider my code.....what problem u have seen in that code? plzz guide.